# VSCode - after last update (1.9.0), all extensions disabled, reload button on all

Tags: visual-studio-code

After I updated my VSCode to the latest version, all of my extensions are now disabled.  Every one of them has a "Reload" button on it, as if I just updated the extension.  If I click the Reload button of any of them, it reloads the window, but they are still all disabled and the reload button is still there.  I expected there to be a fix for this, but evidently I'm the only one experiencing this, since I can't find any posts about it.  Has anyone seen this behavior, and know how to fix it?  I can't use any of my extensions currently...  I've restarted my VSCode, as well as my computer, several times since the update, but that hasn't fixed this.

Here's what the UI looks like:

[image: Extensions Panel]

Answer (score 1):

According to [#19753](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19753), this is a known issue and the fix will be included in the next release.

You could try an [Insider's Build](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders) if you need the fix earlier than that.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the info.  I will just wait for the update, as long as I know the fix will be in there, I'm sure they will release it soon.